# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request on invoke-restmethod using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, azure-powershell, azure-ad-graph-api

I was trying to make api call using Powershell, here is the script

```
$clientID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$tenantName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$ClientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"


$ReqTokenBody = @{
Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
client_Id     = $clientID
Client_Secret = $clientSecret
} 
$TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody
$authheader = @{

    'Authorization' = "Bearer $($Tokenresponse.access_token)"

}
$ssoPatchUri = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/xxxxxxxxxxxxx-b64417d8183c'

$body = @'
{
    "web": @{"redirectUris" = @("https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml")}
    "identifierUris" : @("https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml")
    }
'@

   
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $authheader -Uri $ssoPatchUri -Body $body -Method Patch -ContentType 'application/json' -Verbose
```

The error occurring in the last invoke-restmethod where we passing the $body parameters, i believe its due to the improper framing of nested json.
This is the error which am getting.(Since i did not copied the entire code, line number will not be valid)

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At C:\user\test.ps1:77 char:14
+ ...    $final = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $authheader -Uri $ssoPatchUri  ...
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Here is the actual json data which i need to pass,

```
{
  "web": {
    "redirectUris": [
      "https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
    ] 
  },
  "identifierUris": [
    "https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
  ]    
}
```

Appreciated if someone could help me to fix this

Comment: 400 means the body is not correctly constructed. Why do you use Graph API to update App registration? You can do it with native powershell comandlets https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0 or use powershell Graph module?

Comment: @Hardoman Thanks for the response, I was trying for AZURE AD non-gallery enterprise application. Those native commands will do the job?

Comment: You need to make App registration not enterprise app, it's a different blade in AAD https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-mobile-app-registration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the issue using your code.

[image]

**Steps taken.**

I have granted consent to the following permissions :Application.ReadWrite.All,  Directory.ReadWrite.All, Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy

[image]

I have modified the code a bit  in body and placed content type in authheader.

```js
$TenantName = "****.onmicrosoft.com"
$clientID = "**********"
$clientSecret = "*****************"
$Scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"

$ReqTokenBody = @{
Grant_Type = "client_credentials"
Scope = $Scope
client_Id = $clientID
Client_Secret = $clientSecret
}

$authUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token"

$TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $authUri -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody

$authheader = @{

"Authorization" = "Bearer $($Tokenresponse.access_token)"
"Content-type" = "application/json"

}

$TokenResponse.access_token

$ssoPatchUri = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/####’

$body = '{
"web":
{
"redirectUris": [
"https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
]
},
"identifierUris" : ["https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"]
}'

Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $authheader -Uri $ssoPatchUri -Method PATCH -Body $body

#$v=Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $authheader -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/#######" -Method GET
#$v
#$v.web
```

Here I placed **object id** of the api instead of client id  ( in -Uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/objectId ) to do **PATCH** request and it worked.It was showing the same error when client id is used .

But using client id(https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/ClientId) worked for GET request .

[image]

redirect uri and identifier uri getting updated to the api successfully after using object id in uri for Patch can be shown by using GET request.

[image]

Comment: thanks That helped me framing the json, and i was creating non-gallery app and immediately running the other two PATCH method, because of that it was failing. after placing a wait ie Start-Sleep -s  for 30 seconds before each invoke method it worked.