# HTML email template body is not working with Inline CSS in Microsoft graph API in PowerShell

Tags: html, css, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to send email using service principle in Microsoft Graph API using PowerShell. My email have embedded Image and a HTML body with CSS.

It is giving below error:

```
Invoke-Rest Method : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At D:\Script\Test_Script\powershell script\email_notification.ps1:137 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $UriSend -Headers $Headers1 -Body ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Can anyone give example of using HTML/CSS with Graph API in PowerShell?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You forgot to post the code you're running

Comment: HTML body images are MIME format.  See following for MIME sample : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)  Each MIME attachment starts with two dashes on a new line.

Comment: Please use this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69360899/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-400-bad-request-on-invoke-restmethod-usin